# disable the Security>Local Intranet>enable protected mode from the code

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-like, intranet, protected-mode

How to disable the Security>Local Intranet>enable protected mode from the code?
I am facing problem with facebook like button when this setting is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks God to change security settings from code is not allowed. If they were modifiable by web pages then they didn't serve their purpose (save the user from malicous sites/code).